# Reactivity in component props with expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, solid-js

I'm trying to change inner component behavior by setting him reactive prop. (Working with Solid.js)

```
<Button clicked={clickedKey() === "button1"} onClick={() => setClickedKey("button1")/>
```

I expect that when button will be clicked the signal (state in React) would change and my prop on component will be changed. But it doesn't happen.

Instead I can use this:

```
clickedKey() === "button1" ? 
<Button clicked={clickedKey() === "button1"} onClick={() => setClickedKey("button1")/> :
<Button clicked={clickedKey() === "button2"} onClick={() => setClickedKey("button2")/>
// it can be true and false in 'clicked' property
```

and it will work. Component props in condition (expression) can't be reactive?

Comment: Are you mixing React with Solid?

Comment: It could be you are destruring the props, you should not, Solid Doc is clear on the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SolidJS: Why does destructuring of props cause a loss of reactivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272753/solidjs-why-does-destructuring-of-props-cause-a-loss-of-reactivity)